# How to display pre selected value fecthing from table colmn id and fetch all other records from table in select drop down list in php and mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, selectlist

I have a query where i got stuck . My query is that suppose I have a table where I have 5 records and I want to show all with pre selected . Actually I am modifying the previous records , but I have to fetch only pre selected value of the drop down list of mysql . I need to display as well as pre selected value and rest all others in the list . How we can achieve this. Here is my code:

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<?php
global $a;
global $b;
global $c;
if(isset($_GET['mlid']) && isset($_GET['link']) && isset($_GET['modname']))
{
    $a=$_GET['mlid'];
    $b=$_GET['link'];
    $c=$_GET['modname'];
}
include_once('dbConnection.php');
$view="SELECT * FROM tblviksatprojectmodule WHERE fvModulename='$c'";
$view1="SELECT * FROM tblviksatprojectmodulelink WHERE fiModuleLinkid='$a' and fvModuleLinkname='$b'";
$resultset=mysql_query($view) or die(mysql_errno());
$resultset1=mysql_query($view1) or die(mysql_errno()); 
mysql_num_rows($resultset);
mysql_num_rows($resultset1);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
    <title>VIKSAT Infotech Software Development Company</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h3><marquee direction="left">Viksat Infotech Software Development Company</marquee></h3>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="menu-project-viksat"><a href="index.php">Home</a></div>
        <div id="menu-project-viksat"><a href="index.php?p=1">Project Master</a></div>
        <div id="menu-project-viksat"><a href="index.php">Logout</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="add-project module">
        <form action="" name="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="input-name"><p>Module Name</p>
                <select name="modulename"><?php while($result=mysql_fetch_assoc($resultset)){ ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $result['fiProjectModuleid']; ?>"><?php echo $result['fvModulename']; ?></option><?php } ?>
                </select></div>
                <div class="input-desc"><p>Module Link</p><?php while($result1=mysql_fetch_assoc($resultset1)){ ?>
                    <input type="text" name="modulelink" value="<?php echo $result1['fvModuleLinkname']; ?>" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="modulelinkid" value="<?php echo $result1['fiModuleLinkid']; ?>" /><?php } ?>
                </div>
                <div class="input-btns"><input type="submit" name="sbtn"  value="Save"  class="input-btns-save" />
                    <input type="submit" name="cbtn"  value="Cancel"  class="input-btns-cancel" />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <h3>A Viksat Product</h3>
            <span class="copy-rights"><h4>2017 &copy; Viksat All Rights Reserved</h4></span>
            <span class="txt-rgt">
                <p>Email to : <a href= "mailto:info@viksatinfotech.com">info@viksatinfotech.com</a></p>
            </span>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['sbtn']))
    {
        $module_id=$_POST['modulename'];
        $link_id=$_POST['modulelinkid'];
        $link_name=$_POST['modulelink'];

        $update="UPDATE tblviksatprojectmodulelink SET fvModuleLinkname='$link_name', fiModuleid='$module_id' WHERE fiModuleLinkid='$link_id'";
        mysql_query($update) or die(mysql_errno());
        echo '<script>alert("Your details are updated successfully!")</script>';
        header('Refresh:0,URL=index.php?p=9');
    }
    else if(isset($_POST['cbtn']))
    {
        header('Refresh:0,URL=index.php?p=9');
    }
    ?>
```

Please help me out for how i can do this . Showing pre selected value and all others values . So I can choose another value and update to new one and display records of modifying file.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: still i got no response yet!

please help me out.